# How can I binding variable from directive to controller in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use a `dateDisable` variables to hide the div `date-warp`, the button 'add one', can to change `dateDisable` variable value to `False`, but the button 'add date' can not change variable to `True`. How can I let the code can work? thank you.

#### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="addDateControl">
  <a href="#" ng-click="showDate($event)">add one</a>
  <div clss="date-warp" ng-hide="dateDisable">
    <a href="#" vote-select-list>add date</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
var app = angular.module('GroupApp',[]);
app.controller('addDateControl',
    function ($scope) {
    $scope.dateDisable = true;

    $scope.showDate = function ($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $scope.dateDisable = !$scope.dateDisable;
    };
  })
  .directive('voteSelectList', [ function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.bind('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to do something in your directive like

```
scope.$emit("addedDate");
scope.$apply();
```

Inside your click binding, and in your controller do something like

```
$scope.$on("addedDate", function(){
  $scope.dateDisable = true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! I solved it :)
And push the answer to [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X294cXLybvt4uhDssE8b?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind putting your question on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co) ?

Once you do that, we can have the ability to freely play around with the code. I see two errors from a high level.

- `<div clss="date-warp" ng-hide="dateDisable">` Your class name is missing an "a"
- In your directive, the link function has 3 attributes that are usually very strict concerning what they are. You are currently using `(scope, iElement, iAttrs)` where it should be `(scope, element, attrs)`

From a high-level these may not do anything, but there is a small chance they are what is causing the error. For more about the custom directive properties, check out the AngularJS docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you give me some help, I forgot added to the ng-app, But now I solve this problem.

Have a good day! :)